# How to implement dark/light mode theme with switch in android while ignoring system theme

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making an application and i want to have a switch, which changes the theme of my app and ignores the current system theme.

The way i am doing this is i am writing a string to a config.txt file which is stored in /data dir and when my splash screen is loading, i am getting the string from that file and is changing the theme based on that.

But because of this approach, if i don't put configurationchange="uiMode" in my splash screen activity manifest, it throws error.

```
E/ActivityInjector: get life cycle exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction
    at android.app.ActivityInjector.checkAccessControl(ActivityInjector.java:24)
    at android.app.Activity.onResume(Activity.java:1854)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onResume(FragmentActivity.java:434)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1454)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8051)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4260)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4302)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ClientTransactionHandler.executeTransaction(ClientTransactionHandler.java:57)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityLocally(ActivityThread.java:5331)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3500(ActivityThread.java:224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2054)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7560)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

So i wanted to know is there a better approach for implementing this feature?

My current implementation code:

```
val configFileData = FileReadWrite.readFromFile(this)
    when {
        configFileData.contains("Dark Mode: ON") -> {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
        }
        configFileData.contains("Dark Mode: OFF") -> {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
        }
        else -> {
            FileReadWrite.writeToFile("Dark Mode: OFF",this)
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
        }
    }
```

FileReadWrite is an Object class that i have created to Read/Write data from and to config.txt file.

Comment: Use [shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) for saving simple configs. No need to create a config.txt. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I don't know how to do so, can you link me some references?. I had just started learning Android App Development and this is my first application that i am working on.

Comment: Did you click my link? It links to the official documentation which serves as a good enough tutorial.

Comment: I didn't knew that was a link, mb. Ty for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Preference Data Store](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore) to set the changed theme and observe the change on your MainActivity.

There is a good article [here](https://scalereal.com/android/2020/09/03/hello-datastore-bye-sharedpreferences-android.html) to look at the actual implementation, although you might want to use the `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode` which has certain flags like

1. `AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO`
2. `AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES`
3. `AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM`

for setting up the light/dark mode.

Comment: The problem with the above approach i am getting is that my application is still reacting to system wide theme change which i don't want in the first place. Is there a way i can remove that in the above approach? as the approach works as expected with no issues.